# How to use SSH-Keys with VPS-Servers

Tags: ssh, vps

The Portal where I use my VPS (Vionity), told me to use SSH-Keys, so I downloaded the pre-generated ones and now i am stuck cause I do not know how to install? these now and then how to ssh into the machine. Any clues on both?

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the SSH keys into your `~/.ssh` folder (if it doesn't exist create it via `mkdir -p ~/.ssh`)
2. run `ssh-add ~/.ssh/whatever-the-name-of-the-private-key-is` to add the SSH key into the system (provide password for key if one exists)
3. SSH into the server by running `ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -i ~/.ssh/whatever-the-name-of-the-private-key-is user-name@ip.address.of.vps`